# How do you PutAsync() in firebase in Xamarin

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

**NB: I have a solution but I'm leaving this code up for constructive criticism / help for anyone else who might be struggling with this.**

Hi so I've searched through the forms/examples on github/firebase api and haven't been able to find anything for what I'm doing. It should be pretty simple I just need an example of how to actually do it. (First time working with firebase, only worked with SQL in past)

I have a firebase realtime database, heres the function that registers a new user/driver:

```
public async Task<bool> RegisterNewDriver(string licenceno, string companyname, string vatno, string wasteno )
{
    var result = await firebase
       .Child("RegisterDriverTable")
       .PostAsync(new RegisterDriver() {
         DriverId = Guid.NewGuid(), 
        CompanyName = companyname, 
        VatNo = vatno, 
        WasteNo = wasteno }) ;
    if (result.Object != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

What I want to do is change one variable, ie if the user's CompanyName changes, I want to be able to update the record in the database - updating the CompanyName attribute without effecting the rest of the children like vatno or wasteno.

I've tried this:

```
await firebase
    .Child("RegisterDriverTable")
    .Child(toUpdateDriver.Key)
    .PutAsync(new RegisterDriver()
    {              
         CompanyName = "A Generic Company Inc";       
    });
```

But that just overwrites the driver details.

What I'm currently doing is just kinda doing it manually:

```
     var toUpdateDriver = (await firebase
                        .Child("RegisterDriverTable")
                        .OnceAsync<RegisterDriver>()).Where(a => a.Object.Fk_UserId == (System.Guid)App.Current.Properties["UserGuid"]).FirstOrDefault();

   if (toUpdateDriver != null) {
    var entry = new RegisterDriver() { DriverRange = range };
         await firebase
         .Child("RegisterDriverTable")
         .Child(toUpdateDriver.Key)
         .PutAsync(new RegisterDriver()
         {
            DriverId = toUpdateDriver.Object.DriverId,
            LicenceNo = toUpdateDriver.Object.LicenceNo,
            CompanyName ="A Generic Company Inc",
            VatNo = toUpdateDriver.Object.VatNo,
            WasteNo = toUpdateDriver.Object.WasteNo,
         }); 
     }
```

It works, but it has a lot of redundancy.

Does anyone know how to do this in Xamarin, or does anyone have any examples you could point me to that shows how PutAsync is properly used?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hey user15660763. Great that you were able to solve this on your own. Can you post the solution as an answer below, instead of as an edit in your question? That way both the system and others can more easily now that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought of a solution literally immediately after typing this question out  . I've modified the code above to this which works pretty well. I'll still post the question for anyone who might find this code useful.

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateDriverRange2(int range)
{
    var toUpdateDriver = (await firebase
    .Child("RegisterDriverTable")
    .OnceAsync<RegisterDriver>()).Where(a => a.Object.Fk_UserId == (System.Guid)App.Current.Properties["UserGuid"]).FirstOrDefault();

    if (toUpdateDriver != null)
    {
        toUpdateDriver.Object.CompanyName = "A Generic Company Inc";
        await firebase
           .Child("RegisterDriverTable")
           .Child(toUpdateDriver.Key)
           .PutAsync(toUpdateDriver.Object);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```